# 'vm' object outside Vue instance and called inside method mounted undefined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

When a function is used outside the vue instance and passed inside method mounted, why is the reference to 'vm' lost?

https://jsfiddle.net/z9u39hgu/5/

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app-4',
    data: {
        isLoading: true
    },
    mounted: function() {
        hello();
    }
});


function hello() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(vm));
    //vm.isLoading = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(vm, replacer));
        //vm.isLoading = false;
    })
}

//Extra code ignore
seen = []; 

var replacer = function(key, value) {

if (value != null && typeof value == "object") {
    if (seen.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
        return;
    }
    seen.push(value);
}
return value;

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-4">
    <p v-if="isLoading">Vuejs loading...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `mounted()` is fired from the Vue constructor, i.e. before the `vm` variable can be even assigned. So the `vm` reference is not lost, but it is still undefined when `hello()` is called.

The `timeout()` callback is called later when the `Vue` constructor already returned and `vm` variable is assigned. The chronology of these events is also visible in the console.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app-4',
    data: {
        isLoading: true
    },
    mounted: function() {
        hello();
    }
});


function hello() {
    console.log("before timeout: " + typeof(vm));
    //vm.isLoading = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("after timeout: " + typeof(vm));
        //vm.isLoading = false;
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app-4">
    <p v-if="isLoading">Vuejs loading...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to explain. So what is the best Vue way to write this code? I don't like the idea of using setTimeout. In a second try I passed the 'this' as parameter in the hello function and worked, but err.. Shouldn't Vue deal with it in a better way?

Comment: Maybe you could make the `hello()` function a method within the Vue instance. Then you do not even need to assign `vm` and you can just refer to `this`...  https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/events.html

Comment: Yeah, I could do that or call it outside of the Vue instance. Either way, it will work. Probably I need to change my mind and roll like that.